# How to install programmatically a second instance of the same printer driver

Tags: windows, installation, driver, printers

I need to have two versions of the same driver with different properties under Windows XP and Windows 7.
In need to install it programmatically and in the end there must be two printer drivers listed in the selection of printers of any application. Both drivers should use the same drivers with different properties.

For example. The first printer will be "HP Document Printer" and the second "HP Document Printer 2nd"

The first printer will print with one set of settings and the second will print to a file with other set of settings.

Comment: Take a look at this Super User question and its answers - [Having the same printer installed two times with different configurations][1].


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/430174/having-the-same-printer-installed-two-times-with-different-configurations

Comment: You could use tool to take snapshots of the registry and system files (like regshot for the registry) before and after manually adding a second instance of the same printer to try to see what modifications you have to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a general procedure, the commands and steps that must be followed.